# Puppeteer: how to change navigator attributes before a new tab created with page.click() loads

Tags: puppeteer, navigator

After creating a new page using `browser.newPage()` I load a file with `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()` that consists of dynamically created settings for navigator (like a custom userAgent, language and webdriver's values), later with `page.click()` I click an element on that page, that has the target attribute set to "_blank", so it opens a new tab.

The question is, how can I transfer navigator's changes implemented to the page with clickable element, to the tab created with the click action? -> currently, once the element is clicked and a new tab is created it does not have navigator's changes implemented to the parent page.

<< EDIT>>

I have tested out the below and to my surprise it works for some cases, I assume it is due to some racing conditions. Perhaps somebody could put more light on it.

```
browser.on('targetcreated', async target => {
  if (target.type() === "page") {
    const page = await target.page();
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile);
    await page.setUserAgent(data.userAgent);
    await page.setViewport({
      width: data.viewportWidth,
      height: data.viewportHeight
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either use `page.on('popup', ...)`:

```js
page.on('popup', async(page) => {
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(...);
})
```

or remove the `target="_blank"` from the anchor tag before clicking to force opening in the same tab.

Comment: Removing target="_blank' is not an option for me, because I need a new tab. I will test out the first idea however.

Comment: I know it is a late answer, but as I have verified some time ago, using `page.on('popup', ....)` does not solve the issue, it seems that `page.evaluateOnNewDocument()` does not get triggered with this approach. Removing `target="_blank"` does work, however as long as you need to have a page opened in a new tab, it does not stand for a solution.